# Porque la función de clonar en jquery no esta clonando la animación?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, clone

Hola a todos tengo el siguiente código, básicamente quiero clonar el div (.wavyLinesLeft) que contiene los elementos animados y ponerlos en el div de la derecha, el problema es que me clona los elementos con sus estilos pero no esta clonando la animación, Alguien me puede ayudar, muchas gracias!

```js
// ----- Animación Wavy Lines White ----//
  let xw = []
  for (var i = 0; i <= 120; i++) {
    xw.push(i)
  }
  let t = 0
  function animateW() {
    let points = xw.map(x => {
      let y = 100 + 7 * Math.sin((x + t) / 10)
      return [x, y]
    })
    let path = "M" + points.map(p => {
      return p[0] + "," + p[1]
    }).join(" L")
    document.querySelector("#lineWhithe").setAttribute("d", path)
    t += 0.1
    requestAnimationFrame(animateW)
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".wavyLinesLeft").clone().appendTo(".wavyLinesRight");
  });  

// ----- Animación Wavy Lines Pink ----//
  let xp = []
  for (var i = 0; i <= 180; i++) {
    xp.push(i)
  }
  function animateP() {
    let points = xp.map(x => {
      let y = 100 + 7 * Math.sin((x + t) / 10)
      return [x, y]
    })
    let path = "M" + points.map(p => {
      return p[0] + "," + p[1]
    }).join(" L") 
    document.querySelector("#linePink").setAttribute("d", path)
    t += 0.1
    requestAnimationFrame(animateP)
  }
  

// ----- Animación Wavy Lines Blue ----//
  let xb = []
  for (var i = 0; i <= 240; i++) {
    xb.push(i)
  }
  function animateB() {
    let points = xb.map(x => {
      let y = 100 + 7 * Math.sin((x + t) / 10)
      return [x, y]
    })
    let path = "M" + points.map(p => {
      return p[0] + "," + p[1]
    }).join(" L") 
    document.querySelector("#lineBlue").setAttribute("d", path)
    t += 0.1
    requestAnimationFrame(animateB)
  }
  
   animateP()
   animateB()
   animateW()
```

```css
body{
  background-color:gray;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

path#lineWhithe {
  stroke: #ffffff;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  fill: none;
}

path#linePink {
  stroke: #ff005d;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  fill: none;
}

path#lineBlue {
  stroke: #657DD5;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  fill: none;
}

.wavyLinesLeft{
  border: 1px solid magenta;
  position: absolute;
  width:250px;
  background: transparent;
}

.wavyLinesRight{
  border: 1px solid cyan;
  position: relative;
  width:50%;
  height: 200px;
  background: transparent;
  float: right;
}

.wavyLineTopL{
  position: relative;
  top: 80%;
}
.wavyLineCenterL{
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
}
.wavyLineButtomL{
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Worth Media | Hola</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
 <!-- - - - - - - CSS Styles - - - - - -  -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css">
 <link rel = "stylesheet"  href = "assets/css/magic.css" >
 <!-- - - - - - - JS - - - - - -  -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!-- FADE UP -->
</head>
<body>
 
 <!-- Wavy Lines -->
 <div class="wavyLinesLeft hide">
  <div class="wavyLineTopL">
   <svg>
     <path id="lineWhithe" d="M10,50 L50,100 L90,50"></path>
   </svg>
   <div class="wavyLineCenterL">
    <svg>
      <path id="linePink" d="M10,50 L50,100 L90,50"></path>
    </svg>
    <div class="wavyLineButtomL">
     <svg>
       <path id="lineBlue" d="M10,50 L50,100 L90,50"></path>
     </svg>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="wavyLinesRight">
 </div> 
 
 
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas.  Primero, estas utilizando `id` para identificar los `path` y el id debe de ser unico en el DOM.  Utiliza clases en lugar de ids.  Segundo, `querySelector` solo obtiene el primer elemento en la lista, Utiliza `querySelectorAll` en su lugar.  Quedaria asi:

```js
// ----- Animación Wavy Lines White ----//
  let xw = []
  for (var i = 0; i <= 120; i++) {
    xw.push(i)
  }
  let t = 0
  function animateW() {
    let points = xw.map(x => {
      let y = 100 + 7 * Math.sin((x + t) / 10)
      return [x, y]
    })
    let path = "M" + points.map(p => {
      return p[0] + "," + p[1]
    }).join(" L")
    var list = document.querySelectorAll(".lineWhithe");
    list.forEach(function(line) {
      line.setAttribute("d", path)
    });
    t += 0.1
    requestAnimationFrame(animateW)
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".wavyLinesLeft").clone().appendTo(".wavyLinesRight");
    animateP()
    animateB()
    animateW()
  });  

// ----- Animación Wavy Lines Pink ----//
  let xp = []
  for (var i = 0; i <= 180; i++) {
    xp.push(i)
  }
  function animateP() {
    let points = xp.map(x => {
      let y = 100 + 7 * Math.sin((x + t) / 10)
      return [x, y]
    })
    let path = "M" + points.map(p => {
      return p[0] + "," + p[1]
    }).join(" L") 
    var list = document.querySelectorAll(".linePink");
    list.forEach(function(line) {
      line.setAttribute("d", path)
    });
    t += 0.1
    requestAnimationFrame(animateP)
  }
  

// ----- Animación Wavy Lines Blue ----//
  let xb = []
  for (var i = 0; i <= 240; i++) {
    xb.push(i)
  }
  function animateB() {
    let points = xb.map(x => {
      let y = 100 + 7 * Math.sin((x + t) / 10)
      return [x, y]
    })
    let path = "M" + points.map(p => {
      return p[0] + "," + p[1]
    }).join(" L") 
    var list = document.querySelectorAll(".lineBlue");
    list.forEach(function(line) {
      line.setAttribute("d", path)
    });
    t += 0.1
    requestAnimationFrame(animateB)
  }
```

```css
body{
  background-color:gray;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

path.lineWhithe {
  stroke: #ffffff;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  fill: none;
}

path.linePink {
  stroke: #ff005d;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  fill: none;
}

path.lineBlue {
  stroke: #657DD5;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  fill: none;
}

.wavyLinesLeft{
  border: 1px solid magenta;
  position: absolute;
  width:250px;
  background: transparent;
}

.wavyLinesRight{
  border: 1px solid cyan;
  position: relative;
  width:50%;
  height: 200px;
  background: transparent;
  float: right;
}

.wavyLineTopL{
  position: relative;
  top: 80%;
}
.wavyLineCenterL{
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
}
.wavyLineButtomL{
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Worth Media | Hola</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
 <!-- - - - - - - CSS Styles - - - - - -  -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css">
 <link rel = "stylesheet"  href = "assets/css/magic.css" >
 <!-- - - - - - - JS - - - - - -  -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!-- FADE UP -->
</head>
<body>
 
 <!-- Wavy Lines -->
 <div class="wavyLinesLeft ">
  <div class="wavyLineTopL">
   <svg>
     <path class="lineWhithe" d="M10,50 L50,100 L90,50"></path>
   </svg>
   <div class="wavyLineCenterL">
    <svg>
      <path class="linePink" d="M10,50 L50,100 L90,50"></path>
    </svg>
    <div class="wavyLineButtomL">
     <svg>
       <path class="lineBlue" d="M10,50 L50,100 L90,50"></path>
     </svg>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="wavyLinesRight">
 </div> 
 
 
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Alan, Muchas gracias por tu valiosa ayuda!